# Installation of FreeBSD freezes on VMware

Tags: freebsd, debugging

I am trying to install [FreeBSD](http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/FreeBSD/ISO-IMAGES-i386/9.2/) on VMware by mounting  **FreeBSD-9.2-RELEASE-i386-dvd1.iso**.

The installation proceeds fine untill i reach the following screen

[image]

I have been waiting for an hour and nothing happens so I have assumed that the installation has hanged.

Does anyone have any clue on how to resolve this issue ??

Comment: It's look like a broken ISO-image, loader can't read the kernel into the memory. Also various problems possible depending on the your hardware - whether the system supports VT-x/d etc.

Answer (score 0):

After various days of troubleshooting , it turns out that the issue with because I was using an outdated version of VMWare. Updating the VMWare to its latest version solved this issue for me